# Search for a single date in a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem retrieving data from a table between two dates.
Everything works as it should when two dates differ from each other, but when I want to search for all records from today, it searche nothing:

```
SELECT * from exampletable where created_date >= '2022-10-28' AND created_date<= '2022-10-28'
```

Comment: from today or only today's records ?  Your current select searches today's records

Comment: it works in postgresql for me

Comment: Im using mysql on workbench. I want to search records between two dates. AS you see everything works fine when date differ from each other, but when user want records from today he is going to set today date in column from and today date in column to. And there is no records when searching.

Comment: and you are sure that you have today's records in the example table?

Comment: What is the data type of `created_date`. Please edit your question.

Comment: That means there is no data yet in `exampletable` today.

Comment: There is data from today. When I search for example from yesterday to today its works fine.

created_date is column where creation date is stored.

Comment: But what is the data type? Please post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE exampletable;` along with some sample data inculding the records that should be found by your query.

Comment: If your setup is correct and there are records today, your query will work. See https://dbfiddle.uk/P4xQ6PVo If it doesn't, something with your date column is incorrect or there are no records today.

Comment: Looks like your `created_date` column is DATETIME or TIMERSTAMP, not DATE. In this case you must apply `where created_date >= '2022-10-28' AND created_date < '2022-10-28' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`.

Comment: @Akina Yes. That was the problem. Thank you :)
Sorry everyone for not posting column type

Answer (score 0):

To get all records for a single day using a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` type column you have these options:

```
WHERE DATE(created_date) = '2022-10-28'
```

However - Wrapping a column into a function you will loose the ability to use an index.

Other ways which can use an index:

```
WHERE created_date BETWEEN '2022-10-28 00:00:00' AND '2022-10-28 23:59:59'

WHERE created_date >= '2022-10-28'
  AND created_date <  '2022-10-29'

WHERE created_date >= '2022-10-28'
  AND created_date <  '2022-10-28' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Your query

```
where created_date >= '2022-10-28' AND created_date <= '2022-10-28'
```

is equivalent with

```
where created_date = '2022-10-28'
```

If `created_date` is of type `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` it is the same as

```
where created_date = '2022-10-28 00:00:00'
```

and the query would only return records with the exact time of `00:00:00`.